# Visualizing the shade of images-matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have binary images and I want to convert them into a different type of image.My lecturer told me that "the images that you sent me are not clear, they are binary images,please could you visualize the shade of images". But I did not undestand what he meant. Please help me how can I convert them?

[image: binary image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary image is an image with just two colors, usually black and white. Your lecturer probably want your images to have more colors (this property called color depth), they can be greyscale or colored (RGB). Show us an image example for more help (use Image button when you edit your question).

In general you cannot add more colors with simple comverter. You have to take care of colors when you create/save the image.

Comment: I have just use the mat2gray code and I think it is more clear now.I have added a binary image but I am not sure if you see.

Comment: Yes, I can see your image and it looks binary. Hope with mat2gray you've get better image.

Comment: Yes, it seems better. I sent them to my lecturer and I hope he will like them at this time.Really thanks for your help.